# Cannot get JSON results using PhoneGap and jQuery on iPhone App

Tags: jquery, iphone, json, cordova, jsonp

Currently I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null,function(data) {

       var currencies = [ "USD", "EUR", "JPY", "GBP", "CHF", "AUD", "CAD", "EUR", "SEK", "HKD", "NOK", "NZD", "MXN", "SGD", "KRW", "RON", "BGN", "RUB", "PLN", "DKK" ];
       var myElementToAppendTo = $("#content");

       $.each(data.rates, function(key, value) {
         value2 = 1 / value;
         valueForEuro = value;  
         value = accounting.formatMoney(value, "", 4, ",", "."); 
         value2 = accounting.formatMoney(value2, "$", 4, ",", ".");

         euro = data.rates.EUR;
         value3 = valueForEuro / euro;
         value4 = 1 / value3;
         value3 = accounting.formatMoney(value3, "", 4, ",", "."); 
         value4 = accounting.formatMoney(value4, "&euro;", 4, ",", ".");

            if(jQuery.inArray(key,currencies) > -1) {
                myElementToAppendTo.append('<div class="currencyBox"><div class="currency">'+key+'</div><div class="tab1"><div class="half">'+value+'</div><div class="half">'+value3+'</div></div><div class="tab2"><div class="half">1 '+key+' = '+value2+' </div><div class="half">1 '+key+' = '+value4+' </div></div></div>');
            }
       });

    });
    });


</script>
```

It works on any browser local/server but when I build an iPhone app the JSON results do not display. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you whitelist openexchangerates.org in your plist?

Comment: As I mentioned below, phonegap.plist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to whitelist the server you are connecting to (this can be a wildcard as well).
This is done in your PhoneGap.plist file.
From the Phonegap docs:

> Also, the latest code has the new white-list feature. If you are
>   referencing external hosts, you will have to add the host in
>   PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok. So if
>   you are connecting to "http://phonegap.com", you have to add
>   "phonegap.com" to the list (or use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com" which
>   will match subdomains as well).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but I ended up using a google feeds plugin because it was much easier when I had this same problem. Had to jump through a lot of hoops to do it w/o.

Link: http://jquery.malsup.com/gfeed/

Otherwise you need to modify your plist...

Phonegap reads a setting called 'ExternalHosts' to check what can be allowed.

Open phonegap.plist - the key should in there and you should add a new one for your domain.

Comment: I need to keep JSON due to the nature of the feed.